# Returning an error without throwing an exception with servicestack

Tags: exception, error-handling, servicestack

From what I know, exception throwing can be a little heavy. I can see that [ServiceStack's Error handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) suggests throwing an exception, which gets beautifully serialized to the client side.

**1. How can I do the same without throwing the exception?** - I see I can change the return type to object and return the HttpError instead of throwing, is this the only way?

**2. Will performance improve (vs throwing)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning or throwing a HttpError has the same effect, e.g:

```
return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "SomeErrorCode");
```

Comment: is it a "significant" effect? (like throwing and handling an exception) - if I just want to return a simple error to the user and I don't consider what happen as an exception, should I still use this?

Comment: No, it's just the cost of a C# exception which is un-noticable in the context of a HTTP Request.